# How to execute Robot testcase from eclipse which takes command line list arguments as input?

Tags: python, eclipse, robotframework

I have written a Robot test case which takes input list from command line. I ran the test case from command line and it executed successfully.
All the issue comes when i run the same script from Eclipse, the test case fails and gives a console message -

> 'List variable '@{list_of_vars}' has no item in index 0.'

Below is my code -

```
[Tags]    TestCLI   
    @{list_of_vars}    Split String    ${my_vars}
    Log   @{list_of_vars}[0]
    Log   @{list_of_vars}[1]
```

Syntax used for executing test case from command line:

```
python -m robot -v my_vars:one,two -E space:, -t "TestCLI" C:\Users\user1\eclipse-workspace\RobotTests\robot\firstTest.robot
```

I understood that @{list_of_vars} is looking for input elements when running the test case from eclipse. I have used Run and Start Process keywords to start the command line and couldn't succeed. 
Is there any way to resolve the error and run the same script from eclipse.

**Additional details -**

1. Robot framework version - 3.0.2,
2. Eclipse oxygen,
3. Python version 3.6.4,
4. RED Editor 0.8.3.2018xxx

Comment: Have you tried logging what `${my_vars}` is before trying to split it? Perhaps that will yield some clues.

Comment: @BryanOakley : Yes, tried logging ${my_vars} and here is the result

Comment: @BryanOakley : Here are the logging results                             Starting test: RobotTests.Robot.firstTest.StackOverflowTest
20180404 15:25:29.435 : INFO : 
20180404 15:25:29.437 : INFO : @{list_of_vars} = [ ]
20180404 15:25:29.438 : FAIL : List variable '@{list_of_vars}' has no item in index 0.
Ending test: RobotTests.Robot.firstTest.StackOverflowTest

Answer (score 1):

When running your example I was not able to replicate your results. Instead I observe the desired behavior. Below are the settings I used.

**firstTest.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    String    

*** Test Cases ***

TC
    [Tags]    TestCLI   
    Log    ${my_vars}
    @{list_of_vars}    Split String    ${my_vars}
    Log   @{list_of_vars}[0]
    Log   @{list_of_vars}[1]
```

The additional command line variables `-v my_vars:one,two -E space:,` need to be set on the run configuration.
[image]

This then results in the following **message log**:

```
Starting test: RunWithVars.firstTest.TC
20180404 20:45:06.445 : INFO : one two
20180404 20:45:06.447 : INFO : @{list_of_vars} = [ one | two ]
20180404 20:45:06.448 : INFO : one
20180404 20:45:06.449 : INFO : two
Ending test: RunWithVars.firstTest.TC
```

And **console log**. I've seperated the command into seperate lines and removed some of the `--listener` folder path for readability.

```
Command: C:\Python\RF_P27\Scripts\python.exe 
 -m robot.run 
 --listener C:\Users\..\TestRunnerAgent.py:51805 
 -s RunWithVars.FirstTest 
 -v my_vars:one,two -E space:, C:\TA\W\StackOverflow\RunWithVars
Suite Executor: Robot Framework 3.0.2 (Python 2.7.13 on win32)
==============================================================================
RunWithVars                                                                   
==============================================================================
RunWithVars.firstTest                                                         
==============================================================================
TC                                                                    | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RunWithVars.firstTest                                                 | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
RunWithVars                                                           | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\TA\W\StackOverflow\RunWithVars\output.xml
Log:     C:\TA\W\StackOverflow\RunWithVars\log.html
Report:  C:\TA\W\StackOverflow\RunWithVars\report.html
```

Comment: Currently, I am using some additional arguments in the Run Configurations - i have customized path for output files (debug,report etc.,). And if i want to run the above test i should create a new test suite with separate run configurations as you mentioned above. But what if i have 3-4 tests which reads command line arguments? I should mention the entire list in run configurations.

Comment: If you have multiple robot files, then all of the robot files can be added and through ticking the test case boxes you can remove test cases from the run. This can be separated and saved into individual run configurations, but it's not necessary.

Comment: So i would create different robot tests, create specific run configurations to them and pass arguments. <br> In long term test execution i would run a script which executes all my robot tests so it will be difficult to specify these configurations individually when i run tests in a bulk. <br> By any chance can the run configurations be read from a config file? If so i can update config file according to my tests

Comment: It is possible to use what's called Robot Framework [Argument Files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#argument-files) which allows you to specify a set of arguments in a file and the refer to the file using `robot --argumentfile all_arguments.args`

Comment: Great suggestion. It worked. I have created a Robot Resource file 'all_arguments.robot' where i placed this argument                              **-v    my_vars:one    two**                                                                             and I changed my run configurations as                                                 **--argumentfile resources\all_arguments.robot**                                      and test case executed successfully.

Comment: When the same test case is executed from command line i used this **python -m robot -v my_vars:one,two -E space:, -t "TestCLI" C:\Users\user1\eclipse-workspace\RobotTests\robot\firstTest.robot** . Is there any specific syntax to be followed to create arguments in arguments file? And why the format is different from command line

Comment: The format for the command line and Eclipse Run Config should be the same. So, no specific syntax to be followed beyond what you already do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168314/discussion-between-user2014-and-a-kootstra).